# TextView отображается под CardView

Tags: android, xml, textview, cardview, android-constraintlayout

*Проблема описана в заголовке.* Из-за этого текст **не видно** (его **перекрывает** CardView). Корневое представление - constraint layout. Пожалуйста, с пояснениями, а не по типу "попробуйте это" - и ваш xml код...

Приведу то, что на данный момент у меня:
XML

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/readyThemes"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.68"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H, 0.12"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/readyThemesTopMargin"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardElevation="20dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/ready_themes_bg"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
    android:text="@string/ready_themes"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/readyThemes"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/readyThemes"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/readyThemes"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/readyThemes"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="@dimen/normal_max_text_size"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="@dimen/normal_min_text_size"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="@dimen/normal_step_text_size"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

Comment: Сложно помочь, т.к. вы не описали какой результат ожидаете. Могу лишь предположить, что у вас проблема в том, что карточка имеет Elevation, потому находится как бы выше TextView по оси Z. Если вам нужно чтобы было наоборот - то просто поместить TextView внутрь карточки, а не поверх с помощью привязок. Так она будет отрисовываться внутри карточки, а не под ней/над ней

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Спасибо! Я смог решить проблему. Действительно, elevation влияет на расположение относительно оси Z.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить, что у вас проблема в том, что карточка имеет Elevation, потому находится как бы выше TextView по оси Z. Если вам нужно чтобы было наоборот - то просто поместите TextView внутрь карточки, а не поверх с помощью привязок. Так она будет отрисовываться внутри карточки, а не под ней/над ней.

Ну или просто забать для TextView Elevation больше чем у карточки. Но это будет костыльно и некрасиво (лишняя (?)) тень